# Avaloq script and escaping characters

Tags: avaloq-script

How does one escape characters in string literals in Avaloq scripts? I have been unable to find a definitive answer.

I am trying to include the new line character along with a quote in translation in the AMI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escaping characters is the same as pl/sql, using '' (double single quotes)

And to access the return character, use `util.rtn`

Like this: `'''it''s time''' || util.rtn || 'right?';`